# Could not select single object since multiple objects having the same id and contentDescription

Tags: android, calabash, calabash-android

I am running a calabash-android test and for my query the response is

```
{  
  "id"      =>"recyclerview_businesses",
  "enabled"      =>true,
  "contentDescription"      =>nil,
  "visible"      =>true,
  "tag"      =>nil,
  "description"      =>"android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView@41fdf4a0",
  "class"      =>"android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView",
  "rect"      =>      {  
     "center_y"         =>429,
     "center_x"         =>240,
     "height"         =>120,
     "y"         =>369,
     "width"         =>480,
     "x"         =>0
  }
},
{  
  "id"      =>nil,
  "enabled"      =>true,
  "contentDescription"      =>nil,
  "visible"      =>true,
  "tag"      =>nil,
  "description"      =>"android.widget.LinearLayout@41bdd800",
  "class"      =>"android.widget.LinearLayout",
  "rect"      =>      {  
     "center_y"         =>426,
     "center_x"         =>69,
     "height"         =>114,
     "y"         =>369,
     "width"         =>90,
     "x"         =>24
  }
 },
 {  
  "id"      =>"icon",
  "enabled"      =>true,
  "contentDescription"      =>"Businees",
  "visible"      =>true,
  "tag"      =>nil,
  "description"      =>"com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView@41bbfd60",
  "class"      =>"com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView",
  "rect"      =>      {  
     "center_y"         =>426,
     "center_x"         =>69,
     "height"         =>90,
     "y"         =>381,
     "width"         =>90,
     "x"         =>24
  }
 },
 {  
  "id"      =>nil,
  "enabled"      =>true,
  "contentDescription"      =>nil,
  "visible"      =>true,
  "tag"      =>nil,
  "description"      =>"android.widget.LinearLayout@41f38968",
  "class"      =>"android.widget.LinearLayout",
  "rect"      =>      {  
     "center_y"         =>426,
     "center_x"         =>183,
     "height"         =>114,
     "y"         =>369,
     "width"         =>90,
     "x"         =>138
  }
 },
 {  
  "id"      =>"icon",
  "enabled"      =>true,
  "contentDescription"      =>"Businees",
  "visible"      =>true,
  "tag"      =>nil,
  "description"      =>"com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView@41e08b88",
  "class"      =>"com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView",
  "rect"      =>      {  
     "center_y"         =>426,
     "center_x"         =>183,
     "height"         =>90,
     "y"         =>381,
     "width"         =>90,
     "x"         =>138
  }
 },
 {  
  "id"      =>nil,
  "enabled"      =>true,
  "contentDescription"      =>nil,
  "visible"      =>true,
  "tag"      =>nil,
  "description"      =>"android.widget.LinearLayout@41fe17f8",
  "class"      =>"android.widget.LinearLayout",
  "rect"      =>      {  
     "center_y"         =>426,
     "center_x"         =>297,
     "height"         =>114,
     "y"         =>369,
     "width"         =>90,
     "x"         =>252
  }
 },
 {  
  "id"      =>"icon",
  "enabled"      =>true,
  "contentDescription"      =>"Businees",
  "visible"      =>true,
  "tag"      =>nil,
  "description"      =>"com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView@41ee3028",
  "class"      =>"com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView",
  "rect"      =>      {  
     "center_y"         =>426,
     "center_x"         =>297,
     "height"         =>90,
     "y"         =>381,
     "width"         =>90,
     "x"         =>252
  }
 },
 {  
  "id"      =>nil,
  "enabled"      =>true,
  "contentDescription"      =>nil,
  "visible"      =>true,
  "tag"      =>nil,
  "description"      =>"android.widget.RelativeLayout@4205b0f8",
  "class"      =>"android.widget.RelativeLayout",
  "rect"      =>      {  
     "center_y"         =>500,
     "center_x"         =>240,
     "height"         =>25,
     "y"         =>488,
     "width"         =>480,
     "x"         =>0
  }
 },
 {  
  "id"      =>nil,
  "enabled"      =>true,
  "contentDescription"      =>nil,
  "visible"      =>true,
  "tag"      =>nil,
  "description"      =>"android.view.View@41f8d3d8",
  "class"      =>"android.view.View",
  "rect"      =>      {  
     "center_y"         =>500,
     "center_x"         =>101,
     "height"         =>1,
     "y"         =>500,
     "width"         =>202,
     "x"         =>0
  }
 },
```

Here I wanted to select the **last object** with the id **icon** and contentDescription **Business** . The last one is a button leads to another pop up window. Is there any solution for this issue? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wait_for_element_exists("* id:'icon' contentDescription:'Business'")
last_index = query("* id:'icon' contentDescription:'Business'").length-1
touch("* id:'icon' contentDescription:'Business' index:#{last_index}")
```

Note: It is always better to be explicit. Use a specific index if you know how many buttons there will be (which you most likely will know)

Comment: If you know how many buttons there will be I suggest using a fixed index of 1.

Comment: The number of buttons differs according to the users exist. So I could not fix the number.